# how to retrieve object from sqLite query? having problems

Tags: javascript, sqlite, object

I am querying a local database and trying to retrieve my data in a form of array of objects to be able to manipulate them in another stage.

Below is my code and the scope I can access my object in and where I fail to access the object.

```
 function setStageOneup(){
        var teams = localStorage.teamsUp;
        var tournament_id = 1;
        var statement = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE t_id= '"+tournament_id+"';";
        localStorage.teamsUp = "";
        var team_array = {};
        var myTest = callBack(function(val){

            var team = {};
            for(var i = 0; i < val.rows.length; i++)
            {   
                // teams_array[i]['id'] = val.rows.item(i).id
                 //console.log(val.rows.item(i).text)


                    team.id = val.rows.item(i).id;
                    team.t_id = val.rows.item(i).t_id;
                    team.m_t_id = val.rows.item(i).m_t_id;
                    team.name = val.rows.item(i).name;
                    team.weight = val.rows.item(i).weight;
                    team.goals = val.rows.item(i).goals;
                    team.win = val.rows.item(i).win;
                    team.draw = val.rows.item(i).draw;
                    team.lost = val.rows.item(i).lost;
                    team.misc = val.rows.item(i).misc;
                team_array[i] = team;

                console.log(team); // I am able to hee the output here

            }
            console.log(team_array); // I am able to hee the output here
        },statement);
        console.log(team_array); // I am unable to see here even though the variable is decleared in this scope
    }
```

Thank you, if I missed anything please let me know.

Comment: You know that the callback is executed asynchronously?

Comment: your informing me or questioning me?, How would I go about fixing my Issue please.